# Seems Xcode reference a wrong type of property, use the type of OC header definition instead of Swift definition

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I make an extension of UITextField, and add func like this

```
public struct StyleObject<Base> {
    public let base: Base

    init(_ base: Base) {
        self.base = base
    }
}

extension StyleObject where Base: UITextField {
    @discardableResult public func typingAttributes(_ typingAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]?) -> StyleObject {
        base.typingAttributes = typingAttributes
        return self
    }
}
```

compile error occur

```
(93, 33) Cannot assign value of type '[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]?' to type '[String : Any]?'
```

and when I use Jump To Definition, Xcode jump to the OC header of UITextField, not UITextField.swift

I see the Swift definition in the file

```
open var typingAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]? // automatically resets when the selection changes
```

And UITextField OC Header file define like this

```
@property(nullable, nonatomic,copy) NSDictionary<NSAttributedStringKey,id> *typingAttributes API_AVAILABLE(ios(6.0)); // automatically resets when the selection changes
```

why did this happen?

I'm using Xcode 13.2.1, macOS 12.0.1, Swift 5 build setting.

Xcode 13.4.1 have the same issue.

Comment: What is `base`? We are talking here about the `typingAttributes` of `base`, not of UITextField. Explain `base`.

Comment: I have update the question.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 13.4 and your code, as now provided, compiles just fine for me. Voting to close on the grounds that no issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I create a demo to reproduce the issue. https://github.com/EkkoG/ApplyKitTest, seems it relates to Cocoapods's lib template, with this demo, you can't run the example project.